# Adding .ui file to an existing class in QT

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-designer

could anyone tell me the steps on how to add a .ui file to an existing class in Visual?
Firstly  I added  a new item in Visual, then I chose "QT Dialog Form File" option and I then I created Dialog Form I desire  in QT Designer.

My .h file:

```
(...)
#include "ui_Serial.h"


class Serial : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Serial(QWidget *parent);
    ~Serial();

    Ui::Serial *ui;
(...)
```

My problem is, that I can't use setup ui function:

```
Serial::Serial(QWidget *parent)
: QWidget(parent)
{
    serial = new QSerialPort(this);
    ui->setupUi(this);

}
```

I am getting  this error:
 cannot convert argument 1 from 'Serial *' to 'QDialog *

How I can get pass that?
Any ideas?
Greetings

Answer (score 3):

Each Template has a default class because when the .ui is built, class commands are embedded.

- If you use the template **Widget** your class should be `QWidget`.
- If you use the template **Dialog with Buttons Bottom**, **Dialog with Buttons Right**, **Dialog without Buttons** your class should be `QDialog`.
- If you use the template **MainWindow** your class should be `QMainWindow`.

So we conclude in your case that you should use a class that inherits from QDialog:

***.h**

```
#include "ui_Serial.h"


class Serial : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Serial(QWidget *parent=0);
    ~Serial();

    Ui::Serial *ui;
}
```

***.cpp**

```
Serial::Serial(QWidget *parent):QDialog(parent)
{
    serial = new QSerialPort(this);
    ui->setupUi(this);

}
```